# Conky: Ubuntu 15.10 my RC's now open with a menu bar

Tags: unity, 15.10, conky

I have been running 14.04 for a long time now and I just built a new work PC that 14.04 wouldn't install on (wouldn't recognize GPU during install). After 15.10 install and getting my conky rc's together I have it running them on start as expected. What is not expected is now they have a menu bar/action bar. I can max/min/close each conky window.

How do I get my old conky back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the

> own_window_type

14.04 would allow normal to display without window decorations however 15.10 required desktop